# Why I user imageview and Change Recurce it,I get "out of memory"Error

Tags: android

I Change Image view  For 19 Times In switch And Get This Error
I Change It with Button Click And Change Resource of Image view
When I Debug It I Get Out Of Memory Error

Comment: Post your code . A single line question will not help .

Comment: There may image size issue. Post some code then we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly reduce your image size as compare to normal device and use  "/drawable-nodpi" folder instead of "/drawable" folder

the real problem was the "/drawable" folder! I had all the pictures in "/drawable" generic folder that is considered by the system like "/drawable/mdpi", so when I were running in devices with hdpi or more the images were resized, and became too big which cause OutOfMemoryException!

Now i'm using "/drawable-nodpi" to store my images. This folder works like "/drawable" but the images are never resized!

Answer (score 0):

[**Glide**](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Use this for loading and displaying Images in `ImageView`. It will load the images efficiently and you wont get any `OutOfMemoryError`